# Cant index desired number of docs

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing 1000 json docs in elastic search one by one (just for testing purposes) like this

```
deleteIndex(myIndex);
List<XContentBuilder> docs = new ArrayList<XContentBuilder>();
for (int i=0;i< 1000; i++)
{
   docs.add(createJsonDoc());
}
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)    
{
   client.prepareIndex(myindex, mytype)
            .setSource(docs.get(i))
            .execute();
            //Thread.sleep(10);           
}
```

I noticed that every time I run this code it always indexes less than 1000 docs.
The only way I can get it to index 1000 is if I uncomment the thread.sleep line above.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the response that comes back from ES, some of them are most likely failing.  Here is an extension method we use on all our calls:

```
    internal IRestResponse<T> VerifyResponse<T>(IRestResponse<T> response, Action okAction)
    {
        response.ThrowIfNull("response");

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            if (okAction != null)
            {
                okAction();
            }

            return response;
        }

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            throw new BadRequestException(response);
        }

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unhandled API result: {0}\r\n{1}", response.StatusCode, response.Content));
    }
```